# How do you connect Coda to AWS EC2 Instance? Invalid username or password

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, coda

I have followed the instructions in thread: [How do configure Coda to work for my Amazon EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224778/how-do-configure-coda-to-work-for-my-amazon-ec2-instance)

However, I am still having a problem. I can ssh into my EC2 Instance by just typing `ssh unbuntu@ip` as well as use the terminal in Coda. When I try to add a site and connect- it says User name or Password was not accepted by server.

I am sure my permissions are correct (400) on my keypair located in .ssh as I can ssh into it.

My coda settings are:

```
Protocal: SFTP port 22
Server: <ip>
username: ubuntu
password: <blank>
Root URL: http://<ip>/sub
```

Furthermore,
My .ssh directory permission is 700 and all files within are set to 400.
My config file looks like:

```
Host <ip>
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem
HostName <ip>
```

Any idea what is going wrong? I can ssh through the terminal and use the Coda terminal; however, I says

> "Could not connect to server xxxx: The username or password was not accepted by the server."`

when I try to open the site using Coda.

Answer (score 8):

When creating new sites with Coda for use with EC2 Instances i've used:

> Protocol: SFTP
>
> Port: 22
>
> Server:ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> User Name: ec2-user
>
> Password: (Press the Key Icon and select your Key Pair)
>
> Root URL: http://whatever.com
>
> Remote Root: /var/www/html/whatever.com
>
> Local Root: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Alex/Location/Location/Location

Press SAVE and it's done.

You can also create an `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
# AWS Ec2 Ireland
Host *.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
IdentityFile /location/of/your/pem/file/dublin.pem
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
IdentitiesOnly yes
ForwardAgent no
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the username to "ec2-user" with a blank password.